# Darlington pair. Purpose of components

Tags: bjt, darlington

Giving the following schematic: 
What is purpose of R1 and the diodes ?
[image]

Comment: Not enough context.  Post the surrounding circuit, or where you got the schematic from?  It looks to me like \$R_1\$, \$R_2\$ and the associated diode are there to speed up turning off \$T_2\$.  The diode on the right is either intrinsic (if it's a monolithic Darlington pair) or it's there on purpose because the expected use has the collector voltage falling below the emitter voltage.

Comment: That's the whole circuit. I found it as a "better design of a darlington pair".

Comment: R1 and (R2 + diode) are here to speed up Cbe capacitor discharging time also they make sure that the leakage current does not turn-ON the Darlington.

Comment: But I suspect that this left diode should be connected between B and E terminals.

Comment: The left diode speeds up turning off the 2nd transistor when the B terminal is grounded.

Comment: @pantarhei - Hi, When you include information (text, photos, images etc.) in a question which comes from somewhere else, it helps if you give *full* details of the original source (e.g. title, author, edition and page number etc. if the source is a book, HTML link if the source is a web page, etc.). That helps readers to go to the source for more context and details - similar to [this site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) for answers. Thanks :-)

Comment: Hi, this schematic is from a course presentation and I am not allowed to upload it on the internet. Also the course is in Romanian language and will not be of interest for you. Also there is no context, this schematic is there without an explanation or something.  But is good to know in the future posts to follow your advice.